# Bokeh - Change average based on selected points

Tags: callback, bokeh, interactive

I am following the example given in bokeh tutorials https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/interaction.html to update the average of the selected points. the code is shown below

```
from random import random
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("callback.html")

x = [random() for x in range(500)]
y = [random() for y in range(500)]
color = ["navy"] * len(x)

s = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, color=color))
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="lasso_select", title="Select Here")
p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=8, source=s, alpha=0.4)

s2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(ym=[0.5, 0.5]))
p.line(x=[0, 1], y='ym', color="orange", line_width=5, alpha=0.6, source=s2)

s.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(s2=s2), code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.get('selected')['1d'].indices;
        var d = cb_obj.get('data');
        var ym = 0

        if (inds.length == 0) { return; }

        for (i = 0; i < d['color'].length; i++) {
            d['color'][i] = "navy"
        }
        for (i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            d['color'][inds[i]] = "firebrick"
            ym += d['y'][inds[i]]
        }

        ym /= inds.length
        s2.get('data')['ym'] = [ym, ym]

        cb_obj.trigger('change');
        s2.trigger('change');
    """)

show(p)
```

the average line does not appear to be updating as I select the points, but on the bokeh webpage it works. I am relatively new to Bokeh so appreciate if someone can suggest why it is not working.
Also, What I ultimately want to achieve is to find the average of the minimum and maximum of the selection based on box selection tool. It would be great, if you can also give suggestions on how to modify the above code to suit my requirement.

Regards,
Nit

Comment: You are linking docs from version 0.10 which is many years old and considered obsolete (current version is 2.2.1) Are you actually using version 0.10? If not, you should refer to docs for the actual version you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward way to do this is to use a `Span` as opposed to a line with its own `source`. A span is either a flat or vertical line that spans the entire width/height of the plot it is on. We specify our span here to be a flat line, then we update its location with the average value of the selected data points on the "y" axis. In our callback, we also give it the default case of when 0 elements are selected to change the location of the `Span` to 0.5

```
from random import random
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Span
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("callback.html")

x = [random() for x in range(500)]
y = [random() for y in range(500)]
color = ["navy"] * len(x)

s = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, color=color))
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="lasso_select", title="Select Here")
p.circle(x='x', y='y', color='color', size=8, source=s, alpha=0.4)

slope = Span(location=.5, dimension="width", line_alpha=.6, line_width=5)
p.add_layout(slope)

s.selected.js_on_change('indices', CustomJS(args=dict(s=s, slope=slope), code="""       
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        
        if (inds.length == 0) {
            slope.location = 0.5
            return 
        }
        
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            total += s.data["y"][inds[i]]
        }
        var avg = total / inds.length;
        slope.location = avg;
    """))

show(p)
```